# Want to Count How many Invalid attempt by user for google reCpatcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, google-apis-explorer

I want to  calculate the number of invalid attempt on google reCaptcha by a user in a form.

Thanks.

Comment: Just want to know for analytics purpose that How many invalid attempt came by one user.

Comment: you know from reCaptcha if it was correct or not... and then you need to sum it up...?

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? Show us some code so we can assist further.

Comment: @Atais : I think may be u wrong understood. I want if user selects an invalid images in recaptcha. So want to  know How many times user was not able to clarify captcha.

Comment: @FrankerZ : NO atttempts  because not able to find anything on this on google. Please suggest.

Comment: @SaurabhMahajan You need to at least attempt something...This isn't a "Do everything for me, I'm helpless" website. Clearly, if you've setup your code correctly for recaptcha, you validate the code on the backend to see if it's valid or not, and if it's not valid, you show them the form again with an error message. How about logging it, and then showing them the form?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how google's reCaptcha [work](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/). Actually as you've registered your site to be a reCaptcha client, you've got *site key* and *secret key* from admin pane and all the pass/{not pass} logic is done at google's server. At the same place (server-side) the statistic gets accumulated.

So you visit reCaptcha [online admin panel](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) and you've find your registered sites, the statistic goes along.
[image]

At the above picture you can see the Spam index aka "how many wrong attempts to pass reCaptcha were made at a certain website". It **does not provide statistic  for an indivisual user**. So you should be satisfied with general site statistic that google lets out.

Comment it if not clear.